# Dots of UIPageControl

Tags: ios, iphone, uipagecontrol

I am using `UIPageControl` with `UIScrollView`.

My issue is that the dots of the `UIPageControl` are  also drawing out of the frame of the `UIPageControl`. I am using the following code:

```
m_pUIPageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,410,260,20)];
[m_pUIPageControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[m_pUIPageControl setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
m_pUIPageControl.numberOfPages = 40;
m_pUIPageControl.currentPage = 0;
[m_pUIPageControl setCurrentPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[m_pUIPageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:m_pUIPageControl];
```

How i can control the dots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the frame bigger so that the control is the correct size for the number of page dots.

You can also look at applying a scale transform to the control but be careful not to make the control unusable / ineffective.

Comment: by using CGRectMake(0,410,320,20) still dots are drawing out of screen.

Comment: If you will always have a large number of pages, look at using a custom 3rd party control that doesn't use dots.